# MSYS2 - Install python moviepy

Tags: python, mingw-w64, msys2, moviepy

I am trying to install moviepy python module in msys2 mingw64 (Windows 10).

I tried with pip command, and with compling the source code.
Can you help me please?

Note: I don't know why but

```
$ python -m pip install moviepy
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/python.exe: No module named pip
```

command failed.

```
$ whereis pip
pip: /usr/bin/pip /usr/bin/pip3.8 /mingw64/bin/pip /mingw64/bin/pip3.8
```

Here is the output of `pip install moviepy`:

```
Χρήστος@Chris-pc MINGW64 /c/python/scripts/Papinhio player/notes/moviepy-master
$ pip install moviepy
Collecting moviepy
  Using cached moviepy-1.0.3.tar.gz (388 kB)
Collecting decorator=4.0.2
  Using cached decorator-4.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.2 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm=4.11.2 in /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from moviepy) (4.60.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests=2.8.1 in /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from moviepy) (2.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: proglog=1.17.3
  Using cached numpy-1.20.2.zip (7.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python.exe /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpm3x3dqno
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-9on70z6z/numpy
    Complete output (210 lines):
    Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pxd.in
    Processing numpy/random/bit_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/mtrand.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pyx.in
    Processing numpy/random/_common.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/_mt19937.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/_pcg64.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/_philox.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/_sfc64.pyx
    Cythonizing sources
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blis_info:
      libraries blis not found in ['/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas not found in ['/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_info:
      libraries satlas not found in ['/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blas_info:
      libraries blas not found in ['/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blas_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_clapack_info:
      libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    flame_info:
      libraries flame not found in ['/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib/
    
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib/
    
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/
    
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/
    
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    numpy_linalg_lapack_lite:
      FOUND:
        language = c
        define_macros = [('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_')]

    running dist_info
    running build_src
    build_src
    building py_modules sources
    creating build
    creating build/src.mingw64_nt-10.0-19041-3.2.0-340.x86_64-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/src.mingw64_nt-10.0-19041-3.2.0-340.x86_64-x86_64-3.8/numpy
    creating build/src.mingw64_nt-10.0-19041-3.2.0-340.x86_64-x86_64-3.8/numpy/distutils
    building library "npymath" sources
    Could not locate executable g77
    Could not locate executable f77
    Running from numpy source directory.
    setup.py:485: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
    /tmp/pip-install-9on70z6z/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1989: UserWarning:
        Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
        Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
        A better performance should be easily gained by switching
        Blas library.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    /tmp/pip-install-9on70z6z/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1989: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    /tmp/pip-install-9on70z6z/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1989: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    /tmp/pip-install-9on70z6z/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1849: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    /tmp/pip-install-9on70z6z/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1849: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    /usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 280, in 
        main()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 133, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-2j77iqd8/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 157, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        self.run_setup()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-2j77iqd8/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 248, in run_setup
        super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-2j77iqd8/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setup
        exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
      File "setup.py", line 513, in 
        setup_package()
      File "setup.py", line 505, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "/tmp/pip-install-9on70z6z/numpy/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup
        return old_setup(**new_attr)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-2j77iqd8/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 165, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-2j77iqd8/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/dist_info.py", line 31, in run
        egg_info.run()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-9on70z6z/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/egg_info.py", line 24, in run
        self.run_command("build_src")
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-9on70z6z/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 144, in run
        self.build_sources()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-9on70z6z/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 155, in build_sources
        self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)
      File "/tmp/pip-install-9on70z6z/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 288, in build_library_sources
        sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))
      File "/tmp/pip-install-9on70z6z/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 378, in generate_sources
        source = func(extension, build_dir)
      File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 676, in get_mathlib_info
        raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")
    RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python.exe /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpm3x3dqno Check the logs for full command output.
```

After the suggestion of Xiddoc

`python -m pip install moviepy` goes to same output as `pip install moviepy`

Thanks in advance,
Chris Pappas

Comment: You don't have the `pip` module installed so that you can install other modules. I can't remember how exactly you install `pip`, but try searching on Google to get it installed. After that, you can run your first command again and it will work.

Comment: @Xiddoc pip installed but moviepy doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it.

1. Run `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-python-numpy`
2. Download the source code [from here](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy)
3. Remove numpy requirements from setup.py (line 81)
4. Run `python setup.py build` and `python setup.py install`

Comment: Nice work, but where'd you get the `pacman` command from?

Comment: @Xiddoc check here: https://packages.msys2.org/search?q=numpy

Comment: The library works, but when i run `import moviepy.editor`, this message is saw in the console: `libunwind:      pc not in table, pc=0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` . Is there something i have to change?